# stack ghc error "Invalid Option `--make`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hakyll

I am learning [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/02-basics.html) a library in Haskell.  I need to run

```
ghc --make site.hs
```

However, I instlled ghc with [Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) so I can no longer run `ghc` but instead `stack ghc`

```
$ stack ghc --make site.hs
Invalid option `--make'
```

How am I supposed to compile my `site.hs` ??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stack is interpreting your `--make` as being an option to Stack, not to the GHC subcommand. In order to tell Stack "I'm done giving you options, the rest is for the subcommand," you can use a `--`, e.g.:

```
stack ghc -- --make site.hs
```

Answer (score 4):

the chain of command you are looking for is

```
> stack build
> stack exec -- mysite
```

assuming your cabal file looks like

```
...
executable mysite
  main-is: site.hs
  hs-source-dirs:     app
...
```

if you want to just try running the file without compilation you can use

```
> stack runghc app/site.hs
```